# Accessing submit-button's data attributes in ASP.Net Core MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a submit button, with the following HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="back-button" data-direction="back">Back</button>
```

The controller method is defined like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Index(SearchModel searchModel, string SearchBy, string dataDirection)
{
    // Code removed for simplicity...    
}
```

When I click the button, my Model is populated, but the *dataDirection* property is not populated.

What is the correct way to access those data attributes?

Comment: can we see the form?

Comment: @Legends it is rather lengthy to post here.   The button is within the form.   Is there something specific that you are looking for?

Comment: @eat-sleep-code then let us see the form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a ASP .NET MVC issue.For submit buttons, browsers only send the value of the "value" attribute when the form is submitted. The button's name is used as the parameter name and the value is used as the parameter value.

If you want to send additional parameters with the form based on which button is clicked, you have to use Javascript to listen for the 'click' event of the button and add your custom parameters to the post data or set some hidden field values before submission.

Easiest way is to put a hidden field in your form with name "Direction", listen button click set its value to 'back' or 'next'. And if you have a default value for the direction or you want the last direction value to be set to the hidden field after a postback, you may put a "Direction" property on your model.

Below code shows how you do it with jQuery:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Direction" value="@Model.Direction" id="fldDirection" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   $("[type='submit']").on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).data('direction')) {
         $("#fldDirection").val($(this).data('direction'));
      }
   }
</script>
```